# Cannot retreive focus in TextEdit inside a StackView item

Tags: qt, qml

I do not understand why it does not work properly. I want to set TextEdit focus to true when the window pops out. TextEdit can receive key events only after a click has been performed on its area.

`main.qml`

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id:aplWin
    visible: true
    minimumWidth:  1280
    minimumHeight: 1024

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: SignInWin {}
    }
}
```

`SignInWin.qml`

```
Page {
    id: root
    width: parent.width + 500
    height: parent.height

    Rectangle {
        border.color: "black"
        y: 200
        width: 50
        height: 20
        z: 1
        TextEdit {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "black"
            focus: true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to `forceActiveFocus()` when `Component.onComplete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are those:

You have multiple layers in your focus tree. Each `FocusScope` can have one child that has focus. So now you have:

```
StackView -> Page -> TextEdit
```

What puzzles me, is that `Page` acts as if it were a `FocusScope`, but is not documented that way.

This means, that `TextEdit` won't have `activeFocus` unless the `Page` *AND* the `StackView` have. But `activeFocus` is required to retrieve the input.

So, you can either use the method `forceActiveFocus()` which will iterate over the focus hierarchy, and requesting the focus for each `FocusScope`, or you set the `focus`-property to `true` for each layer in the hierarchy.

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id:aplWin
    visible: true
    minimumWidth:  1280
    minimumHeight: 1024

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: SignInWin {}
        focus: true // <--- HERE!
    }
}

Page {
    id: root
    width: parent.width + 500
    height: parent.height
    focus: true // <--- AND HERE

    Rectangle {
        border.color: "black"
        y: 200
        width: 50
        height: 20
        z: 1
        TextEdit {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "black"
            focus: true
        }
    }
}
```